# Display different dashboard for different users on login

Tags: user, dashboard

Is there any way I can default which dashboard is displayed for a user logging in? I don't mean the same dashboard with different permissions for different users - I mean a completely different dashboard to the default for the org with different components. A personalised dashboard.

Update: I see there's an idea for this which is 3 years old.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X41QAE

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, [Allow users to select a dashboard on their lightning home page](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003X41QAE) is an idea asking for this functionality.

What you do have is:

- Ability to create different lightning home pages for different profiles. See [Build a Custom Home Page for Lightning Experience trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_homepage).
- Within that home page, you could drag multiple dashboards on the page with specific conditions to display only for certain users. This design won't help if you need 50+ differences for 50+ users, but it will help if you have specific groups of users that need different dashboards (ex. Sales Leads view  vs. Open Opportunities vs. Manager dashboard).
- You could look on appexchange, there's [Dashboard Pal](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000Ecs3hUAB) which seems like it might provide what you're looking for (I have not used this so I cannot say for sure if it's good or meets the need). See description of it below

> The lightning component enables the user to choose a dashboard from a
> list of available folders in the org, upon selecting a dashboard this
> dashboard is saved for current user, replacing the default dashboard
> for that user in order to avoid having that user having to select a
> dashboard every time, therefore making the user interaction
> persistent.

Comment: I did have a look at DashBoard Pal and we might go with this one. We have 30 orgs so having multiple dashboards is not going to work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a checkbox or pick list field on the user object and setup conditions around those to display different dashboards in lightning app builder.